# Dynamically add link buttons in ASP.Net/VB.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I make dynamically add link buttons to a form in asp.net(vb.net)?

Here is the code I tried:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <% For index As Integer = 1 To 10 %>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="#EVAL<%=index%>" runat="server"><%=index%></asp:LinkButton>
    <% Next %>
</form>
```

I tried dynamically using panel, but this create problem when use `br` tag then that will not give new line.

That code

```
Dim lk As LinkButton

For index As Integer = 1 To 10
    lk = New LinkButton
    lk.ID = index
    lk.Text = index
    Panel1.Controls.Add(lk)
Next
```

Comment: It's really not clear you're asking.

Comment: Use the "code" button to format your code instead of using ` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to loop through them on the front end code, I would recommend using a panel and adding the controls to that.

First you would create your panel:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ASP:Panel Runat="server" ID="Panel1" />
</form>
```

Then on the code behind, you would create your links dynamically and add them to that panel:

```
    For index As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim lk As New LinkButton
        lk.ID = index
        lk.Text = index
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lk)
    Next
```

If you need to wire events up to each link, you would use the AddHandler and attach the proper sub:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For index As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim lk As New LinkButton
        lk.ID = index
        lk.Text = index
        AddHandler lk.Click, AddressOf DoSomething
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lk)
    Next
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Handle click here
End Sub
```

To resolve the issue with a line break, simple create a label with a <br> tag in it:

```
    For index As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim lk As New LinkButton
        lk.ID = index
        lk.Text = index
        AddHandler lk.Click, AddressOf DoSomething
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lk)

        Dim lbl as new label
        lbl.text = "<br>"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to create a `<BR/>` tag dynamically?

Try this:

```
Dim lk As LinkButton 
Dim br as HtmlGenericControl

 For index As Integer = 1 To 10
     lk = New LinkButton
     lk.ID = index
     lk.Text = index
     Panel1.Controls.Add(lk)

     br = New HtmlGenericControl("br")
     Panel1.Controls.Add(br)
 Next
```

This is all from memory, but that's the general idea.

ETA:  BTW, I'm not sure `index` will work as the link button ID.  I think IDs need to start with an alpha character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnk1 = new LinkButton();
            lnk1.Text = "testtest";

            LinkButton lnk2 = new LinkButton();
            lnk2.Text = "test";
            pnl1.Controls.Add(lnk1);
            pnl1.Controls.Add(lnk2);
        }
    </script>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I did it using a mix of the previous answers. Also gets data form a mysql database to populate the panel with buttons.

- now set up the available audits for this client
- they will be based on the id and the audits table
- now get data from audits table

Code

```
    Dim myStrSql As String = "SELECT audit,user_id,total_questions FROM audits WHERE user_id = " & myGlobalId & ";"
    Dim mySet As New DataSet
    Dim myda As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myAudit As String = ""
    Dim myTotalQuestions As Integer = 0

    openMySql()

    myda = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(myStrSql, myConnection)
    myda.Fill(mySet, "SOURCE")

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    If mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows.Count - 1
            myAudit = IIf(IsDBNull(mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows(i).Item("audit").ToString), "", mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows(i).Item("audit").ToString)
            myTotalQuestions = IIf(IsDBNull(mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows(i).Item("total_questions").ToString), 0, CInt(mySet.Tables("SOURCE").Rows(i).Item("total_questions").ToString))
            'now create a button for each
            Dim btn As New Button()
            btn.ID = "btn_" & Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(myAudit, ",", ""), ".", ""), ":", ""), ";", ""), ":", ""), "?", "")
            btn.Text = myAudit & " : " & myTotalQuestions & " questions."
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf MenuButtonClick
            Panel1.Controls.Add(btn)
            'this puts in a new line in the panel
            Dim lbl As New Label
            lbl.Text = "<br>"
            Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
        Next

    End If
End If
```